# Select distinct values from one table and join non matching values from second table to create new rows

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables I'm trying to combine into one. They don't have a matching key besides the ID. I need to look up distinct value in table 1 (Zip) and add every value listed in table 2 (activity). All activities are unique (about 20+), but I summarized them below. I can't seem to find any solutions online.

Table 1

```
     ID    City       State  Zip 
     1     Houston    TX     77009
     2     Miami      FL     33101
     3     Cleveland  OH     44101
     4     Boston     MA     02108
     5     Rochester  MN     14602
```

Table 2

```
    ID     Activity
    1      Park
    2      Playground
    3      Dog Park
    4      Walking trail
    5      Treasure
```

Expect output for new table

```
    ID    City       State    Zip    Activity
     1     Houston    TX     77009   Park
     2     Houston    TX     77009   Playground
     3     Houston    TX     77009   Dog Park
     4     Houston    TX     77009   Walking Trail
     5     Houston    TX     77009   Treasure
     6     Miami      FL     33101   Park
     7     Miami      FL     33101   Playground
     8     Miami      FL     33101   Dog Park
     9     Miami      FL     33101   Walking Trail
     10    Miami      FL     33101   Treasure
     11    Cleveland  OH     44101   Park
     12    Cleveland  OH     44101   Playground
     13    Cleveland  OH     44101   Dog Park
     14    Cleveland  OH     44101   Walking Trail
     15    Cleveland  OH     44101   Treasure
```

The best I've come with is listed below, but I can't figure out how to loop it. I appreciate any help.

```
SELECT * FROM places AS A
LEFT JOIN geocache_activities AS b 
ON a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result looks like a simple "cross join":

```
INSERT INTO new_table (city, state, zip, activity)
   SELECT p.city, p.state, p.zip, ga.activity
     FROM places AS p
     JOIN geocache_activities AS ga;  -- with no ON clause
```

Note that the original `id` (presumably `AUTO_INCREMENT`) are ignored and presumable there is an new `id AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `new_table`.

It is probably "unwise" to build such a table, since you can do the `JOIN` whenever you need the combination.